# Implementation of Combining Faster R-CNN and U-net Network for instance segmentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, faster-rcnn

I saw an article discussing "Combining Faster R-CNN and U-net Network for Efficient Whole Heart Segmentation", has anyone seen such an implementation on github or such ?
I want to create an instance segmentation model which can preform well on biological images (arabidopsis  seedlings).

I would appreciate if someone could give me some feed back :)